# Vertically aligning image in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to vertically align an image in the second column of a tabPanel in Shiny. I have managed to align it horizontally (using align="center"), but cannot align it vertically without inserting several br(). I highly suspect there must be a more elegant solution to do this. An example of my code is below (br()'s not included). Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                        tabPanel("Plot", 
                                 column(width = 6,
                                        plotOutput("plot")),
                                 column(width = 6, align="center",
                                        img(src = "image.jpg", height=140, width=140),
                                        )),
                        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

A not so great solution that greatly reduces the br() congestion:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

n_br <- 17

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Plot", 
                             column(width = 6,
                                    plotOutput("plot")),
                             column(width = 6, align="center",
                                    map(1:n_br, ~br()), #add n number of br() 
                                    img(src = "image.jpg", height=140, width=140),
                             )),
                    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
        )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit:

Following [this tutorial](https://html-online.com/articles/image-align-center/) and using shiny's tags function:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Plot", 
                             column(width = 6,
                                    plotOutput("plot")),
                             column(width = 6, align = "center",
                                    tags$style(HTML('
                                        .verticalcenter {
                                        display: table-cell;
                                        height: 400px;
                                        vertical-align: middle;
                                        }')),
                                    tags$div(class = "verticalcenter", img(src = "image.png", height = "140px", width = "140px"))
                             )),
                    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
        )
    ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you suggested and it works. More elegant than multiple br()s! I was wondering whether it can be done wrapping the img command in html but I have not found an example.

Comment: I edited the post to include an html way, hope it is useful.

Comment: Thanks! This is in line with what I was thinking of. The only issue is that it makes the image very large. Basically it fills the whole column. I wanted to keep the original size, just have it centered horizontally and vertically in the column. So I tired setting "height: 140 px" instead of 400 px, and also adding "width: 140 px (to keep the size as the original picture)", but it did not have any effect. It still filled the whole column.

Comment: I updated the code with the correct size.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was after. It looks like first you need to set the size of the table-cell bigger than the size of the picture, which I did not do before.